# typescript runtime array type .map method available

Tags: javascript, arrays, types, typescript

I've got following piece of code:

```
  if (Array.isArray(value.items)) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply(items, value.items.map(function(item, key) {
      return traverseCallback(item, path.concat(['items', key]), resolve);
    }));
  }
```

that is throwing an error on `value.items.map`. The error is:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'IObjectSchema | IObjectSchema[]'.
```

The thing is - I deal either with a `IObjectSchema` element or an array of such elements. When I go down into `Array.isArray...` then I'm 100% sure I've got an array, hence I've got `.map` function available on the array. This is obvious JS.

However, TypeScript seems unconvinced that it has the `.map` available, probably, it doesn't recognize `Array.isArray...` call one level up.

The question is - how can I use a variable as if it was either a typed element or a typed element array and allow to use .map if it is an array? I'm sure my code is JS-correct, but TS throws errors here.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right about not having the `map` method on type `IObjectSchema | IObjectSchema[]`, so you need to tell it that after the `if` it's safe to assume that you're dealing with `IObjectSchema[]`.

You have two options:

(1) Cast

```
if (Array.isArray(value.items)) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply(items, (value.items as IObjectSchema[]).map(function(item, key) {
        return traverseCallback(item, path.concat(['items', key]), resolve);
    }));
}
```

(2) Use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

```
if (value.items instanceof Array) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply(items, value.items.map(function(item, key) {
        return traverseCallback(item, path.concat(['items', key]), resolve);
    }));
}
```

Seems like what you did is similar to my 2nd solution, but the compiler doesn't recognize the type guard when using `Array.isArray`.
You can only use `typeof` or `instanceof`.

You can also create your own type guard if you still want to use `Array.isArray`:

```
function isObjectSchemaArray(items: IObjectSchema | IObjectSchema[]): items is IObjectSchema[] {
    return Array.isArray(items);
}
```

And then:

```
if (isObjectSchemaArray(value.items)) { ... }
```

Comment: I used 2nd approach `if (value.items instanceof Array) {` and it still returns the same error, dunno why

Comment: Oh right. Using type guards on dotted properties is [supported only from typescript 2.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#dotted-names-in-type-guards).  Try using the `isObjectSchemaArray` approach I provided